# Designing app to load, edit, and save hierarchical data

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, telerik-grid, hierarchical-data

I am writing a GUI that will be integrated with SAP Business One.  I'm having a difficult time determine how to load, edit, and save the data in the best way possible (reliable, fast, easy).

I have two tables which are called Structures and StructureRows (not great names).  A structure can contain other structures, generics, and specifics.  The structures rows hold all of these items and have a type associated with them.  The generics are placeholders for specifics and the specifics are an actual item in inventory.

A job will contain job metadata as well as n structures.  On the screen where you edit the job, you can add structures and delete structures as well as edit the rows underneath them.  For example, if you added Structure 1 to Job 1 and Structure 1 contains Generic 1, the user would be able to swap Generic 1 for a Specific.

I understand how to store the data, but I don't know what the best method to load and save the data is...

I see a few different options:

1. When someone adds a structure to a job, load the structure, and then recursively load any structures beneath it (the generics and specifics will already be loaded).  I would put this all into an Object Model such as List and each Structure object would have List and List.  When I save the changes back to the database, I would have to manually loop through the data and persist the changes.
2. Somehow load the data into a view in SQL and then group and order the datatable/dataset on the client side.  Bind the data to a GridView so changes are automatically reflected in the dataset.  When you go to save, SQL / ADO.NET could handle this automatically?  This seems like the ideal solution, but I don't know how to actually implement it...

The part that throws me off is being able to add a structure to a structure.  If it wasn't for this, I would select the Specifics and Generics from the StructureRows table, and group them in the GUI based on the Structure they belong to.  I would have them in a DataTable and bind that to the GridView so any changes were persisted automatically to the DataTable and then I could turn around and push them to SQL very easily...

Is loading and saving the data manually via an object model the only option I have?  If not, how would you do it?  I'm not sure if I'm just making it more complicated then it needs to be or if this is actually difficult to do with C#, ADO.NET and MS SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HierarchyID datatype was introduced in SQLServer 2008 to handle this kind of thing.  Haven't done it myself, but here's a [place to start](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2008/10/17/hierarchies-with-hierarchyid-in-sql-2008.aspx) that gives a fair example of how to use it.

That being said, if you aren't wedded to your current tables, and don't need to query out the individual elements (in other words, you are always dealing the job as a whole), I'd be tempted to store the data for each job as XML. (If you were doing a web-based app, you could also go with JSON.)  It preserves the hierarchy and there are many tools in .NET for working with XML.  There's also a built-in [TreeView class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for winForms, and doubtless other third party controls available.

Comment: I ended up saving the extra data related to a job in XML.  It kind of seems like a cop out, but I needed something working and it seems fine so far!